# WPF what is the best way to cache an image data

Tags: wpf, image, byte, bitmapimage

I have an application where I get lot of images in the form of byte[],
I store them in the memory for later use by the user demand

Should I store them in byte[]? or there is another way to store them for quicker loading on user demand?

My code that loads the image is like this

```
    private static BitmapImage LoadImage(byte[] imageData)
    {
        if (imageData == null || imageData.Length == 0) return null;
        var image = new BitmapImage();
        using (var mem = new MemoryStream(imageData))
        {
            image.BeginInit();
            image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            image.StreamSource = mem;
            image.EndInit();
        }
        image.Freeze();
        return image;
    }
```

Thank you!
Ron

Comment: You get the images in byte[] but is that how you use them?

Comment: I just edited to show how i use it... when the returned image the the ImageControl.Source

Comment: Would you accept an answer based upon the weak reference pattern?  That seems to be what you need...

Comment: If you want the images to be loaded lazily, just use [OnDemand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapcacheoption.aspx).

Comment: @nmclean Then you wouldn't be able to close the stream right after EndInit. See the Remarks [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.streamsource.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could store the images in a Dictionary.
The key is the unique identifier  (E.G. Int32).

The image could be stored as byte[] or BitmapImage

If you store it as BitmapImage you have to convert the byte[] up front
But then you don't need to convert on demand

```
Dictionary<Int32, byte[]>  
or
Dictionary<Int32, BitmapImage>
```

Pretty sure BitmapImage is going to be bigger so converting on demand would use less memory.
Your question said a lot of images but you also asked for quicker user loading.
Test both ways.